# Looking for books on complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, book-recommendation

As the title says, I am looking for some good self-study books on complex analysis. I am an undergraduate student studying computer engineering in Romania. The thing is I have this course that would translate as "special mathematics" and I haven't paid attention until now, so I have to recuperate everything on my own. All the books on complex analysis that I've seen so far cover a lot of other topics  and I don't have the time to get to the topics I am looking for until the exams. So I'm searching for some good books covering only or being as closely as possible to the following topics: complex functions, Cauchy's formulas, series of complex functions, power series, Laurent series, Contour integration, residues, distributions, convolution etc. Excuse me for any mistakes as I am not a native english speaker.

Comment: Perhaps [Schaum's Outline in *Complex Variables*](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0071615695) (see also [here](https://archive.org/details/schaumsoutlineof0000spie_o0x7)). I used this as a strong supplement (to course texts by Marsden, Ahlfors, Conway, etc.) when studying for my Ph.D. exam in complex analysis, mainly for practice with computational aspects and various straightforward/short proofs. However, I don't believe it has anything on distributions or convolution. Maybe use selected sections in other books for those topics, with the Schaum's Outline as your main book?

Comment: Schaum’s outlines are excellent, this was my first thought as well, +1 for you

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend ($1$) [Bak-Newman's Complex Analysis](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781441972873), ($2$) [Ivan Wilde's Lectures on Complex Analysis](https://www.maa.org/publications/maa-reviews/lecture-notes-on-complex-analysis) and ($3$) [Sarason's Complex Function Theory](https://bookstore.ams.org/mbk-49/). You might also want to try [Asmar-Grafakos' Complex Analysis with Applications](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319940625).

Answer (score 0):

I learnt from [Marsden's Basic Complex Analysis](http://math.sjtu.edu.cn/faculty/victorm/marsden_hoffman.pdf), which I think is great for self-study also.

Answer (score 0):

Complex Variables and Applications by Brown and Churchill or read 'very easy to understandable' book by Edward B. Saff, Arthur David Snider - Fundamentals of complex analysis, with applications. Third one is Complex Variables by Ablowitz and Fokas.

Answer (score 0):

The following link gives an Amazon review to a book that I am using for self-study, that I really like.

https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R2U8HSQP51VII4/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=038797427X

In my opinion, the review, which includes criticism of the book, is dead on accurate.